# Flat UI Checkbox Styling Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a rails application and styling with Flat UI. I'm currently using the flatui-rails gem in conjunction with the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. Everything is working fine except when checkboxes are dynamically added to the page. The styling isn't being associated with those checkboxes, but it is being associated with checkboxes are already loaded into the DOM.

I was following [this](https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI-Pro-Support/issues/89) issue with the flatui-rails gem but I can't seem to get this tidbit of code working:

```
$(document).on("click", "#accounts_for_title", function() {
  $(':checkbox').checkbox();
});
```

I've tried it in the flatui-rails gem and application.js in my rails app, but I keep getting a checkbox method not defined.

Is there a better place that I should put this hack?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a switch, you could try:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  // ...
  success: function(response) {
  // Once you append html then just execute this jQuery code to initialize the switch checkbox....
    jQuery('your-selector').append(response);
    jQuery("[data-toggle='switch']").wrap('<div class="switch" />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
  }
});
```

The above is initializing the switch after you append the checkbox dynamically.

```
jQuery("[data-toggle='switch']").wrap('<div class="switch" />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Amy changes you make in your local version of the gem won't be reflected in your app, as the gem itself isn't changed.

The place to put your javascript is either on the page where you want it, in a 'content_for :head' block, or in a separate js file in your app.

Comment: I forgot to add, that at first I had that functionality in application.js in my rails app and it still threw the same error.

Comment: Yes. I don't have any problems with any of my js.